# Help - use PHP-broswer, or proxy or get_page_contents or include page, or something else?

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a web application for which I need to capture a specific user-driven event (such as mouse dblclick) occurring on a different-website page loaded through my website.

What I want to do is :

1. User visits my website - hosted by me.
2. There, user types in any website URL (e.g.: http://www.example.com)
3. That URL page gets loaded as is.
4. When user double-clicks mouse over any link or image from that page, a popup/side-panel is displayed with content related to that particular image or link.

I can do this with a combination of PHP get_page_contents or include-page, and javascript dblclick.
However, when user clicks on any link or submits a form, the control goes to that other website, where I cannot show the side-panel.
I might be able to handle the links by proxifying them when user clicks on any of them. How do I handle forms submission and other stuff ?
I can use a full-featured proxy, but that will be too heavy just for the purpose of capturing the event.

My question is that is there a way to write some kind of light PHP script that sits on my website - that loads other websites contents as is, but lets me capture the mouse-dblclick event to show related-content in the side panel .

I have already searched the internet, but could not find anything.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: yikes, this is more of a flash thing i'd say, otherwise like the pekka said, you'll go crazy over the amount of ajax involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds way too complicated to ever get reliably working IMO. Proxifying complex requests on 3rd-party pages? Maybe even with some additional AJAX that you'd have to proxify too? I may be wrong, but *I* think you'll go *crazy* and get swamped with complaints about sites not working.

I don't know what your web application is supposed to do but I would strongly consider building a Firefox extension (that has much more rights to access and do things on 3rd party sites) or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

My application is supposed to fetch keywords from the double-clicked link and show related content/images based on those. For example if the link contains keywords "Labrador" "dog", the application will show related content such as "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labrador_Retriever" link, labrador dog picture etc. in the side-panel. 

I agree that an extension will be better, but very few people actually go install and use extensions. That is why I am looking for a possible alternative.

Comment: @userlite I see. I'm afraid all the tools I know that do similar things are in fact extensions, I've never seen one that works as a normal web application - probably with good reason...

Comment: oh ok. I'll think it over. Thanks Pekka .